# Tag: TextLayoutCache Text: Cache Value deleted

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

While debugging my Android app at certain point I'm seeing a huge amount of entries in the LogCat with the

```
Tag: TextLayoutCache Text: Cache Value 0x51b9f578 deleted, size=168 (the hexa value changes from entry to entry)
```

Does anyone know what this about? Memory leak? Any ideas how to solve it if it is a problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer on the net, so I had a look at the code for [TextLayoutCache.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/jni/android/graphics/TextLayoutCache.cpp). Looks fine to me. It's caching text layout data to improve performance, and there's currently a fixed default cache size of 0.5MB defined in [TextLayoutCache.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/jni/android/graphics/TextLayoutCache.h).

So if you're changing layout text to a fixed set of values (<0.5MB), you won't see the log message.

If you change text to dynamic values then eventually the cache will fill and the LRU (least recently used) cache entry is deleted, and you'll see the log message. It's just a debug message, not an error, not a leak. It's a useful performance metric about how Android internals are handling our App.

Note that TextLayoutCache isn't used in Android versions >= 5.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue when I was updating my textView values from handler using runnable &

I collected instance of textViews by findViewById() into variables, then updating values of textview by referring these collected instances.

So, as i observed I don't need instance of that textview outside of my hander so I simply use findViewById()inside handler and updated my textviews.

write your findviewById() in context you need id.(talking about inside brackets of your function using it.. in my case.)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but anyways, despite if it works, I keep not understanding the error, How/When/What it's being cached.

BTW, I checked and I use the reference in multiple places, so I don't want to be calling the findbyid each time I use a method in the class instead of having just one reference and use it.

Comment: As I mention i came across this while updating textView from thread running continuously. If you don't call findViewById it adds those lines to your logcat. It's not related to memory leak, I've answered the question with reason why it's happening (in my case).

Comment: Ok, I've tried it know, but keeps saying so, might be a different problem. Thanks anyways!