# How to stop this message in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

When I run my app on actual device I am continuously getting this message in logcat

```
E/TextLayoutCache: TextLayoutCache is present
```

what is the meaning of this message and how to stop logcat of showing it.

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449835/tag-textlayoutcache-text-cache-value-deleted

Answer (score 0):

It's caching text layout data to improve performance, you can configure the logcat to show what you need to see

[image: edit config]